# MEF create object explicitely

Tags: .net, spring, mef

I am trying to create objects explicitely, similar to Spring `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method which creates objects with all the dependencies initialised within that object, I am not aware about MEF much , I tried searching web for the same but could not find the method to explicitely invoke creation of object with all its dependencies initialised,

Does anybody know the method which allows explicitely creating objects with all of its imports initialised ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ExportedType instance = compositionContainer.GetExportedValue<ExportedType>();
```

Where `compositionContainer` is your `CompositionContainer` instance and `ExportedType` is the type that you want to create/get an instance for.

How can you get an instance of `CompositionContainer`?
Use the following code once:

```
CompositionContainer compositionContainer = CompositionHost.Initialize(catalog);
```

Where `catalog` is your MEF catalog (usually an instance of `AggregateCatalog`).